# How to import additional code into class file

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, titlesec

I was inspired by the article "Fancy chapter headings with TikZ" (Stefan Kottwitz many thx) and I have created the whole fancy sectioning. But what I need to do now is to import this whole code for sections and chapter into my REPORT CLASS because I dont want this code to be in my project. 
For example when I will start my new project and will add the `\documentclass[svgnames]{report}` and will begin document with `\section{bla bla}` so the edited sectioning in report class will be automatically applied for the `\section{bla bla}` command.

I am asking for some help because I have never ever played with the latex files and classes.

Comment: Would it not be more convenient to put this in your own custom package? Then you could just write: `\usepackage{myfancysections}`. If you really want it in the class, consider cloning article.cls, but I would not suggest it. It is way less partible then putting this in your own package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your class, I added some useful packages and options

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But you can remove if you want, I added also

```
 \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
```

useful for `TikZ`

and finally

```
\RequirePackage{etex} 
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
```

But you can also remove these packages. You need to save the next code in a file names myreport.cls.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]% standard latex package works with this format
\ProvidesClass{myreport}% we give the name of the new class (here myreport) and we give
  % some informations about date of creation and the aim of the document 
[2012/03/27\space Version:\space 1.0\space myreport documentation class]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
 % more complex We create a new class based on an existing class and we want to use the   
  options of report
\ProcessOptions\relax% this is the way to process the options, Stephan gave the good link    
 for clsguide.pdf
\LoadClass[]{report}  % add options if necessarry , we can create personal options
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
  % To avoid clash with xcolor,  \PassOptionsToPackage is the good macro to pass options
  % tikz loads xcolor, and if you want some extra colors, you need to use xcolor with 
  % dvipsnames,svgnames ( see xcolor.pdf ). But you need to make before loading tikz.
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  % I recommend to use utf8 but you can prefer latin1. You can adapt this line.
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  % personally  I don't use this line because I work with fourier font and fourier.sty 
  % loads  automatically [T1]{fontenc}. 
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{etex} 
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e} 

% colors
\definecolor{fHlavicky}{RGB}{124,252,0}
\definecolor{fPisma}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fCHaSEK}{RGB}{255,127,0}
\definecolor{fSSaSSS}{RGB}{0,191,255}

\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\newcommand*\sectionlabel{}
\newcommand*\subsectionlabel{}
\newcommand*\subsubsectionlabel{}

%CHAPTER
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3.2cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=fHlavicky] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.7,yshift=.07\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=fCHaSEK]
              {\color{fPisma}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

%SEKCTION
\titleformat{\section}
{\gdef\sectionlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\LARGE\bfseries\slshape}
  {\gdef\sectionlabel{\thesection\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=west,xshift=.2\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=7pt,inner sep=3pt,
              fill=fCHaSEK]
              {\color{fPisma}\sectionlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      }

%SUBSEC.
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\gdef\subsectionlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\upshape}
  {\gdef\subsectionlabel{\thesubsection\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=west,xshift=.2\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=5pt,inner sep=2pt,
              fill=fSSaSSS]
              {\color{fPisma}\subsectionlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      }

%SUBSUBSEC.
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\gdef\subsubsectionlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\upshape}
  {\gdef\subsubsectionlabel{\thesubsubsection\ }}{0pt}
  {\color{fSSaSSS}\subsubsectionlabel#1}


\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-210pt}{5pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-180pt}{5pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-30pt}{5pt}{10pt}   
\endinput
```

Now you use the class :

```
\documentclass{myreport}
\begin{document}
 \section{Introduction} 
   \section{Suite} 
   \subsubsection{intro-suite}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. I had to do some modifications cuz of lots of errors for my example document. But this helped me a lot. But i have few questions because i want to also understand some things for future:
Q1: What advantage gives me " \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}" ?
Q2:Can you give me some short cooments for the first 5 lines in myreport.cls.
ONE MORE TIME :) THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: Yes I will add some comments

Answer (score 6):

Easiest solution:

1. Make a class file `myreport.cls` consisting of your code.
2. Add `\LoadClass{report}` at the beginning.
3. Look at [`clsguide.pdf`](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) for further administrative stuff like `\ProvidesClass` you should add.
4. Use with `\documentclass{myreport}`.